# Merging two lines of code into one using indexing or any other tool

Tags: r, indexing

I have two differnet lines of code which performing same thing but for two different columns. I tried different methods to merge them into just one line of code but everytime I get an error.

Code is just to tranform datetime column from chr to dttm:

```
df[["started_at"]] <- as.POSIXct(df[["started_at"]], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") %>% ymd_hms()
df[["ended_at"]] <- as.POSIXct(df[["ended_at"]], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") %>% ymd_hms()
```

Comment: Hi @RFadl, could you please share your data using `dput(df)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: If yyou are already coercing to POSIXct with `as.POSIXct`, then there's no point in piping to `ymd_hms` . It's completely redundant, it changes nothing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are comfortable with the package `dplyr`, you can use `mutate()` with `across()`.

#### Input

I've created a dummy dataframe `df` for demonstration.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# dummy dataframe
df <- tibble(started_at = "2020-01-30 11:11:11", 
             ended_at = "2020-12-06 15:43:26", 
             ID = "123")

# A tibble: 1 × 3
  started_at          ended_at            ID   
  <chr>               <chr>               <chr>
1 2020-01-30 11:11:11 2020-12-06 15:43:26 123
```

#### Solution

```
df <- df %>% mutate(across(c(started_at, ended_at), 
                           ~ as.POSIXct(.x, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") %>% 
                             ymd_hms()))

# A tibble: 1 × 3
  started_at          ended_at            ID   
  <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>
1 2020-01-30 11:11:11 2020-12-06 15:43:26 123
```

Answer (score 1):

Any of

```
df %>% mutate(across(c(started_at, ended_at), as.POSIXct))
df %>% mutate(across(c(started_at, ended_at), ymd_hms))
```

will coerce to class `"POSIXct"`.
If you know that the date/time columns are the only ones ending in `"_at"` , you can simplify the code above to any of

```
df %>% mutate(across(ends_with("_at"), as.POSIXct))
df %>% mutate(across(ends_with("_at"), ymd_hms))
```

On both case, the rule is

- If you want to avoid loading another package, `lubridate`, just for this, use the code line calling `as.POSIXct`.
- If you need more date and time functions, to load and use package [`lubridate`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=lubridate) is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

As the OP showed `base R` code, a `base R` variant for simultaneously transforming multiple columns at once can be with `lapply`

```
df[c("started_at", "ended_at")] <- lapply(df[c("started_at", "ended_at")], 
        as.POSIXct)
```

The `format` is only needed if it not in the default format.  With `POSIXct/POSIXlt`, default `format` is `YYYY-MM-HH` which is the format as showed in the OP's post